# How do I click the search button in Yahoo finance

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to simplify a spreadsheet and would like your help. I've got the following code where I search for APPL stock in Yahoo finance. How do I hit the click button? I believe the issue I have is "search-button" in last line of the code.

```
Sub browsetosite()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "www.finance.yahoo.com"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL

   IE.Document.forms("input").elements("yfin-usr-qry").Value = "APPL"
   IE.Document.forms("input").elements("**search-button**").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry it's not a direct answer, but have you looked at the URL Yahoo returns when you do search for a stock?  `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL` - why not just use `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/` then just add the stock symbol you want to look up?

Comment: I've got exactly what you recommend to click search below but it doesn't click search...the code above only writes APPL in search box and leaves it there - no further action.
IE.Document.forms("input").elements("search-button").Click

Comment: Hmm - that's odd.  I edited in a .gif of it working. Are you positive there's no other code running that may perhaps prevent it from loading?  What if you step through with `F8` (like I do in my example)?  EDIT: Ah! If I just run normally, it does the same. Fills in AAPL but no clicking. One second.

Comment: Agreed! Line by line works (F8) but not all in one go...

Comment: Okay, see my edited Answer.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked! (You can mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark left of the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after testing, it looks like the issue is that Yahoo's page loads a *lot* of things.

I added a ten second wait, before you add the Stock Symbol.  Play around with the timing, you can likely cut that down some.

```
Sub browsetosite() 
   Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

   IE.Visible = True
   IE.navigate "www.finance.yahoo.com"

   Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   Loop
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
   IE.Document.forms("input").elements("yfin-usr-qry").Value = "APPL"
   IE.Document.forms("input").elements("search-button").Focus
   IE.Document.forms("input").elements("search-button").Click
End Sub
```

But, as mentioned above, if you know the symbols you want to lookup, you would likely be better off instead just navigating directly to `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/[SYMBOL]`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a requirement for any waiting or focus. Use IDs to target where possible as much faster and CSS selectors are much quicker than your current syntax.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub BrowseToSite()
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "www.finance.yahoo.com"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[name='yfin-usr-qry']").Value = "APPL"
            .querySelector("#search-button").Click
        End With
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?